# How to make the angles in a polar plot go clockwise with 0° at the top

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib and numpy to make a polar plot. Here is some sample code:

```
import numpy as N
import matplotlib.pyplot as P

angle = N.arange(0, 360, 10, dtype=float) * N.pi / 180.0
arbitrary_data = N.abs(N.sin(angle)) + 0.1 * (N.random.random_sample(size=angle.shape) - 0.5)

P.clf()
P.polar(angle, arbitrary_data)
P.show()
```

You will notice that 0° is at 3 o'clock on the plot, and the angles go counterclockwise. It would be more useful for my data visualization purposes to have 0° at 12 o'clock and have the angles go clockwise. Is there any way to do this *besides* rotating the data and manually changing the axis labels?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found it out -- matplotlib allows you to create custom projections. I created one that inherits from `PolarAxes`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes, register_projection
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D, Bbox, IdentityTransform

class NorthPolarAxes(PolarAxes):
    '''
    A variant of PolarAxes where theta starts pointing north and goes
    clockwise.
    '''
    name = 'northpolar'

    class NorthPolarTransform(PolarAxes.PolarTransform):
        def transform(self, tr):
            xy   = np.zeros(tr.shape, np.float_)
            t    = tr[:, 0:1]
            r    = tr[:, 1:2]
            x    = xy[:, 0:1]
            y    = xy[:, 1:2]
            x[:] = r * np.sin(t)
            y[:] = r * np.cos(t)
            return xy

        transform_non_affine = transform

        def inverted(self):
            return NorthPolarAxes.InvertedNorthPolarTransform()

    class InvertedNorthPolarTransform(PolarAxes.InvertedPolarTransform):
        def transform(self, xy):
            x = xy[:, 0:1]
            y = xy[:, 1:]
            r = np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
            theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
            return np.concatenate((theta, r), 1)

        def inverted(self):
            return NorthPolarAxes.NorthPolarTransform()

        def _set_lim_and_transforms(self):
            PolarAxes._set_lim_and_transforms(self)
            self.transProjection = self.NorthPolarTransform()
            self.transData = (self.transScale + self.transProjection + (self.transProjectionAffine + self.transAxes))
            self._xaxis_transform = (self.transProjection + self.PolarAffine(IdentityTransform(), Bbox.unit()) + self.transAxes)
            self._xaxis_text1_transform = (self._theta_label1_position + self._xaxis_transform)
            self._yaxis_transform = (Affine2D().scale(np.pi * 2.0, 1.0) + self.transData)
            self._yaxis_text1_transform = (self._r_label1_position + Affine2D().scale(1.0 / 360.0, 1.0) + self._yaxis_transform)

register_projection(NorthPolarAxes)

angle = np.arange(0, 360, 10, dtype=float) * np.pi / 180.0
arbitrary_data = (np.abs(np.sin(angle)) + 0.1 * 
    (np.random.random_sample(size=angle.shape) - 0.5))

plt.clf()
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='northpolar')
plt.plot(angle, arbitrary_data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this should be included with their custom projection examples.

Comment: @ptomato - I think the answer needs an update for a commit that was made 2012-01-23 (git log -Sself._r_label1_position). Not sure which version that ended up in. In any case there is no self._r_label1_position anymore and removing that line seems to solve the problems.

Comment: In that case it should be updated to match whatever `PolarAxes` looks like now...

Comment: The question was how to get a polar plot with zero at the top and angles increasing clockwise. The example output is a plot with zero to the right and angles increasing counterclockwise. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 33):

Updating this question, in Matplotlib 1.1, there are now two methods in `PolarAxes` for setting the theta direction (CW/CCW) and location for theta=0.

Check out 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/devel/add_new_projection.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes

Specifically, see `set_theta_direction()` and `set_theta_offset()`.

Lots of people attempting to do compass-like plots it seems.

Comment: If you have an polar axis *ax*:     **ax.set_theta_offset(0.5*numpy.pi)**

Answer (score 24):

To expand [klimaat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005575/klimaat) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302530), with an example:

```
from math import radians
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

angle=[0.,5.,10.,15.,20.,25.,30.,35.,40.,45.,50.,55.,60.,65.,70.,75.,\
       80.,85.,90.,95.,100.,105.,110.,115.,120.,125.]

angle = [radians(a) for a in angle]

lux=[12.67,12.97,12.49,14.58,12.46,12.59,11.26,10.71,17.74,25.95,\
     15.07,7.43,6.30,6.39,7.70,9.19,11.30,13.30,14.07,15.92,14.70,\
     10.70,6.27,2.69,1.29,0.81]

plt.clf()
sp = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
sp.set_theta_zero_location('N')
sp.set_theta_direction(-1)
plt.plot(angle, lux)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- [matplotlib: Developer's guide for creating scales and transformations](https://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes)

Answer (score 4):

You could modify your matplotlib/projections/polar.py.

Where it says:

```
def transform(self, tr):
        xy   = npy.zeros(tr.shape, npy.float_)
        t    = tr[:, 0:1]
        r    = tr[:, 1:2]
        x    = xy[:, 0:1]
        y    = xy[:, 1:2]
        x[:] = r * npy.cos(t)
        y[:] = r * npy.sin(t)
        return xy
```

Make it say:

```
def transform(self, tr):
        xy   = npy.zeros(tr.shape, npy.float_)
        t    = tr[:, 0:1]
        r    = tr[:, 1:2]
        x    = xy[:, 0:1]
        y    = xy[:, 1:2]
        x[:] = - r * npy.sin(t)
        y[:] = r * npy.cos(t)
        return xy
```

I didn't actually try it, you may need to tweak x[:] and y[:] assignments to your taste. This change will affect all programs that use matplotlib polar plot.

Comment: This is ingenious, but patching the code is kind of cheating, isn't it? However, you've given me an idea. Matplotlib allows you to create axes with any kind of transformation; perhaps I can write an alternate polar() function with the transform I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Both invert routines should use the full path to the transforms:

```
return NorthPolarAxes.InvertedNorthPolarTransform()
```

and

```
return NorthPolarAxes.NorthPolarTransform()
```

Now, automatically created subclasses of NorthPolarAxes such as NorthPolarAxesSubplot can access the transform functions.

Hope this helps.