# Set polar plot to have 0 degrees at the top

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have created a simple polar plot using matplotlib. I'm trying to make the plot with 0 degrees at the top (12 o'clock position) rather than the right-hand side (3 o'clock position). I can't see any simple way to do this in the matplotlib documentation.

I've found an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417794/how-to-make-the-angles-in-a-matplotlib-polar-plot-go-clockwise-with-0-at-the-top) here on StackOverflow, but the accepted answer doesn't seem to work, and as it's over a year old I thought there may be a better way to do it now.

Any ideas?

Comment: The linked transformation example works for me on python 2.7 matplotlib 1.0.1   Can you provide errors/problems you encounter?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `angle` with `angle - pi/4`?

Comment: This doesn't fix the labels on the plot.